# Vector subscript out of range - Update Method

Tags: c++, vector, header-files, directx-10

I'm having an error.

"Vector subscript is out of range, line 932."

I have two enemy types, an array of asteroids and then a single enemy on it's own. They are made exactly the same except the asteroids are multiple in number, and the Borg is on it's own. I've tracked the error down to the Borg's update method, which is exactly the same as the Asteroids method with some name changes for the Borg. I've tried changing the "for" to "if" and I have tried to change the vector array to a D3DXVECTOR3. I think it's an array error but my programming knowledge is limited. Here are the update methods:

asteroidgamestate.h

```
#ifndef ASTEROIDSGAMESTATE
#define ASTEROIDSGAMESTATE

 #include "Game Engine.h"
 #include "Game Constants.h"
 #include <vector>

 class AsteroidsGameState:public GameState
{
private:
        // STL vector to hold a collection of asteroid game sprites.
        std::vector<GameSprite*> m_pAsteroids;
        // STL vector to hold motion vectors for each asteroid.
        std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3*> m_vAsteroidMotionVectors;
        // STL vector to hold scaling factors for each asteroid.
        std::vector<D3DXVECTOR2*> m_vAsteroidRotation; 

public:
    AsteroidsGameState() { }
    ~AsteroidsGameState() 
        {
        this->Release();
        }

    //Initialises Asteroids & Borg cube
    virtual bool Init() 
        {
        D3DXVECTOR3 cSpritePosition;
        GameSprite* asteroid;
        D3DXVECTOR3* motionVector;
        D3DXVECTOR2* rotation;
        // Set up the asteroids.
        for (int i = 0; i < MaximumNumberOfAsteroids / 2; i++)
            {
            asteroid = new GameSprite();
            if (!asteroid->Init(420,425,true,L"asteroid.png"))
                return false;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            asteroid->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector
            asteroid->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            asteroid->SetAlive();
            asteroid->SetVisible();
            float scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(100, 1000)/3000.0f);
            asteroid->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            asteroid->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            this->m_pAsteroids.push_back(asteroid);
            motionVector = new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            motionVector->x = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->z = 0.0f;
            this->m_vAsteroidMotionVectors.push_back(motionVector);
            rotation = new D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            rotation->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            this->m_vAsteroidRotation.push_back(rotation);
            }


            for (int i = MaximumNumberOfAsteroids / 2; i < MaximumNumberOfAsteroids; i++)
            {
            asteroid = new GameSprite();
            if (!asteroid->Init(420,425,true,L"asteroid2.png"))
                return false;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            asteroid->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector
            asteroid->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            asteroid->SetAlive();
            asteroid->SetVisible();
            float scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(100, 1000)/3000.0f);
            asteroid->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            asteroid->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            this->m_pAsteroids.push_back(asteroid);
            motionVector = new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            motionVector->x = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->z = 0.0f;
            this->m_vAsteroidMotionVectors.push_back(motionVector);
            rotation = new D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            rotation->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            this->m_vAsteroidRotation.push_back(rotation);
            }

            //Spawns one Borg
            for (int i = 2 / 2; i < 2; i++)
            {
            asteroid = new GameSprite();
            int BorgHealth = 4;
            if (!asteroid->Init(420,425,true,L"borgcube.png"))
                return false;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            /*if (BorgHealth < 4)
            {
                D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f);
            }*/
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            asteroid->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector
            asteroid->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            asteroid->SetAlive();
            asteroid->SetVisible();
            float scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(999, 1000)/3000.0f);
            asteroid->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            asteroid->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            this->m_pAsteroids.push_back(asteroid);
            motionVector = new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            motionVector->x = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->z = 0.0f;
            this->m_vAsteroidMotionVectors.push_back(motionVector);
            rotation = new D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            rotation->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            this->m_vAsteroidRotation.push_back(rotation);
            }

        return true;
        }

    // Update pposition, rotation of asteroids.
    virtual void Update() 
        {
        GameSprite* asteroid;
        int i = 0;
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pAsteroids.begin(); it != m_pAsteroids.end(); it++)
            {
            asteroid = *it;
            if (m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->y <= 0)
                m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->x -= m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->y;
            else
                m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->x += m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->y;
            asteroid->SetRotationMatrix(m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->x);
            i++;
            if (i >= MaximumNumberOfAsteroids)
                i = 0;
            if (asteroid->GetAlive())
                {
                asteroid->SetTranslationMatrix(*m_vAsteroidMotionVectors[i]);
                asteroid->Update();
                }
            asteroid->CheckBoundary();
            }
        }

    // At this time no action is required on entering the state.
    virtual void Enter() { }

    // At this time no action is required when leaving the state.
    virtual void Exit() { }

    // Render asteroids.
    virtual void Render() 
        {
        GameSprite* asteroid;
        // Render all the asteroids.
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pAsteroids.begin(); it != m_pAsteroids.end(); it++)
            {
            asteroid = *it;
            asteroid->Render();
            }
        }
    // Free allocated resources.
    virtual void Release() 
        {
        // Remove Vector classes containing game objects.
        this->FreeSTL(m_pAsteroids);
        this->FreeSTL(m_vAsteroidMotionVectors);
        this->FreeSTL(m_vAsteroidRotation);
        }

    // Getter functions.
    // Get the STL vector to hold a collection of asteroid game sprites.
    std::vector<GameSprite*> GetAsteroids() { return this-> m_pAsteroids; }
    // Get the STL vector to hold motion vectors for each asteroid.
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3*> GetAsteroidMotionVectors() { return this->m_vAsteroidMotionVectors; }
    // Get the STL vector to hold scaling factors for each asteroid.
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR2*> GetAsteroidRotation() { return this->m_vAsteroidRotation; }

// Private template function to free allocatted resources.
private:
    // Template methods to help destroy game objects.
    template<typename T>
    void FreeSTL(std::vector<T*> &list)
        {
        std::vector<T*>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        while(it != list.end())
            {
            if ((*it) != NULL)
                {
                delete (*it);
                it = list.erase(it);
                }
            else
                it++;
            }
        list.clear();
        }

    // New game level requires bringing the asteroids back to life.
    void NextLevelOfAsteroids() 
        {
        GameSprite* asteroid;
        D3DXVECTOR3 cSpritePosition;
        float scale;
        int i = 0;
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pAsteroids.begin(); it != m_pAsteroids.end(); it++)
            {
            asteroid = *it;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            asteroid->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector.
            asteroid->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            asteroid->SetAlive();
            asteroid->SetVisible();
            // Scale the asteroids.
            scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(100, 1000)/3000.0f);
            asteroid->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            asteroid->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            // Set motion vectors for the asteroids.
            m_vAsteroidMotionVectors[i]->x =  (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            m_vAsteroidMotionVectors[i]->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            // Set up rotation vector for the asteroids.
            m_vAsteroidRotation[i]->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            i++;
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

borggamestate.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BORGGAMESTATE
#define BORGGAMESTATE

#include "Game Engine.h"
#include "Game Constants.h"
 #include <vector>

 class BorgGameState:public GameState
{
private:
        // STL vector to hold a collection of borg game sprites.
        std::vector<GameSprite*> m_pBorg;
        // STL vector to hold motion vectors for the borg.
        std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3*> m_vBorgMotionVectors;
        // STL vector to hold scaling factors for the borg.
        std::vector<D3DXVECTOR2*> m_vBorgRotation; 

public:
    BorgGameState() { }
    ~BorgGameState() 
        {
        this->Release();
        }

    //Initialises Borg cube
    virtual bool Init() 
        {
        D3DXVECTOR3 cSpritePosition;
        GameSprite* borg;
        D3DXVECTOR3* motionVector;
        D3DXVECTOR2* rotation;
        // Set up the borg.

            //Spawns one Borg
            for (int i = 2 / 2; i < 2; i++)
            {
            borg = new GameSprite();
            int BorgHealth = 4;
            if (!borg->Init(420,425,true,L"borgcube.png"))
                return false;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            /*if (BorgHealth < 4)
            {
                D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f);
            }*/
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            borg->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector
            borg->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            borg->SetAlive();
            borg->SetVisible();
            float scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(999, 1000)/3000.0f);
            borg->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            borg->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            this->m_pBorg.push_back(borg);
            motionVector = new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            motionVector->x = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            motionVector->z = 0.0f;
            this->m_vBorgMotionVectors.push_back(motionVector);
            rotation = new D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            rotation->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            this->m_vBorgRotation.push_back(rotation);
            }

        return true;
        }

    // Update position, rotation of borg.
    virtual void Update() 
        {
        GameSprite* borg;
        int i = 0;
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pBorg.begin(); it != m_pBorg.end(); it++)
            {
            borg = *it;
            if (m_vBorgRotation[i]->y <= 0)
                m_vBorgRotation[i]->x -= m_vBorgRotation[i]->y;
            else
                m_vBorgRotation[i]->x += m_vBorgRotation[i]->y;
            borg->SetRotationMatrix(m_vBorgRotation[i]->x);
            i++;
            if (i >= MaximumNumberOfAsteroids)
                i = 0;
            if (borg->GetAlive())
                {
                borg->SetTranslationMatrix(*m_vBorgMotionVectors[i]);
                borg->Update();
                }
            borg->CheckBoundary();
            }
        }

    // At this time no action is required on entering the state.
    virtual void Enter() { }

    // At this time no action is required when leaving the state.
    virtual void Exit() { }

    // Render borg.
    virtual void Render() 
        {
        GameSprite* borg;
        // Render borg.
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pBorg.begin(); it != m_pBorg.end(); it++)
            {
            borg = *it;
            borg->Render();
            }
        }
    // Free allocated resources.
    virtual void Release() 
        {
        // Remove Vector classes containing game objects.
        this->FreeSTL(m_pBorg);
        this->FreeSTL(m_vBorgMotionVectors);
        this->FreeSTL(m_vBorgRotation);
        }

    // Getter functions.
    // Get the STL vector to hold a collection of borg game sprites.
    std::vector<GameSprite*> GetBorg() { return this-> m_pBorg; }
    // Get the STL vector to hold motion vectors for each borg.
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3*> GetBorgMotionVectors() { return this->m_vBorgMotionVectors; }
    // Get the STL vector to hold scaling factors for the borg.
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR2*> GetBorgRotation() { return this->m_vBorgRotation; }

// Private template function to free allocatted resources.
private:
    // Template methods to help destroy game objects.
    template<typename T>
    void FreeSTL(std::vector<T*> &list)
        {
        std::vector<T*>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        while(it != list.end())
            {
            if ((*it) != NULL)
                {
                delete (*it);
                it = list.erase(it);
                }
            else
                it++;
            }
        list.clear();
        }

    // New game level requires bringing the borg back to life.
    void NextLevelOfBorg() 
        {
        GameSprite* borg;
        D3DXVECTOR3 cSpritePosition;
        float scale;
        int i = 0;
        std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it;
        for (std::vector<GameSprite*>::iterator it = m_pBorg.begin(); it != m_pBorg.end(); it++)
            {
            borg = *it;
            // Set the sprites current position.
            cSpritePosition.x = (float)(100 + MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(0, Graphics2D::Get().GetWindowWidth() - 100));
            cSpritePosition.y = 1.0f;
            cSpritePosition.z = 0.9f;
            borg->SetSpritePosition(cSpritePosition);
            // Set the sprites motion vector.
            borg->SetTranslationMatrix(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            borg->SetAlive();
            borg->SetVisible();
            // Scale the borg.
            scale = ((float)MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(100, 1000)/3000.0f);
            borg->SetScaleMatrix(scale, scale);
            borg->SetRotationMatrix(0.0f);
            // Set motion vectors for the borg.
            m_vBorgMotionVectors[i]->x =  (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            m_vBorgMotionVectors[i]->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/150.0f) + 0.25f;
            // Set up rotation vector for the borg.
            m_vBorgRotation[i]->y = (float)(MathsUtilities::Get().GetRandomNumber(-1000, 1000)/10000.0f) + 0.001f;
            i++;
            }
        }
};
```

## endif

Thanks for your help, and sorry if I've missed anything.

Comment: Which line is line 932?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say with the information provided, but
your problem might be the here:

In BorgGameState.h Update()

```
        borg = *it;
        if (m_vBorgRotation[i]->y <= 0)
            m_vBorgRotation[i]->x -= m_vBorgRotation[i]->y;
        else
            m_vBorgRotation[i]->x += m_vBorgRotation[i]->y;
        borg->SetRotationMatrix(m_vBorgRotation[i]->x);
        i++;
        if (i >= MaximumNumberOfAsteroids) // <--- should this be MaximumNumberOfBorg instead?
            i = 0;
```

If m_vBorgRotation has fewer elements than MaximumNumberOfAsteroids you will get such an error.

Comment: I've updated the code, with full code for each class. Sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: Managed to fix it, thanks very much. That was exactly the error. Have a great day. :)